# Rellenar Spinner con mi lista de Sqlite

Tags: java, android

Tengo un `Spinner` con tres posiciones *0, 1, 2* y lo que quiero realizar es crear más posiciones con una *lista* que tengo en mi `Sqlite`:

```
  final List lista = mDatabase.ReadCategorias();
```

`Activity`

```
   int flags[] = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3};

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        if (position == 0) {
            tv_categoria.setText("diaria");
            tv_imagen.setText("image_0001");
        } else if (position == 1) {
            tv_categoria.setText("semanal");
            tv_imagen.setText("image_0002");
        } else if (position == 2) {
            tv_categoria.setText("mensual");
            tv_imagen.setText("image_0003");
        }
        spin.setSelection(position);
    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    // fin spinner

    SqliteDatabase mDatabase;
    TextView tv_categoria, tv_imagen;
    String[] categoria;
    Spinner spin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crear_nota);

        tv_categoria = new TextView(CrearNota.this);
        tv_imagen = new TextView(CrearNota.this);
        mDatabase = new SqliteDatabase(this);
        spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnercategoria);

      // spinner

        /// aqui cargo de un array los títulos de los tres primeros

        categoria = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titulos_categorias);
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(ContextyMetodos.getAppContext(), flags, categoria);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        spin.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        // fin spinner
```

`Adapter`

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    int flags[];
    String[] titulo_categorias;
    LayoutInflater inflter;

    public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, int[] flags, String[] titulo_categorias) {
        this.context = applicationContext;
        this.flags = flags;
        this.titulo_categorias = titulo_categorias;
        inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return flags.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_items, null);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagenspinner);
        TextView names = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textspinner);
        icon.setImageResource(flags[i]);
        names.setText(titulo_categorias[i]);
        return view;
    }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo realizarlo? Gracias!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo como podrías hacer, está el código comentado:

```
    //obtienes el primer array
    String[] categoria = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titulos_categorias);
    //obtienes la lista de tu DB
    List lista = mDatabase.ReadCategorias();
    //conviertes la lista en un array
    String[] listaEnArry = (String[])lista.toArray(new String[lista.size()]);
    //creas un nuevo array con el tamaño de los dos anteriores
    String[] arrayFinal = new String[listaEnArry.length + categoria.length];
    //juntas ambos array usando System.arraycopy que es mas eficiente
    System.arraycopy(categoria, 0, arrayFinal, 0, categoria.length);
    System.arraycopy(listaEnArry, 0, arrayFinal, categoria.length, listaEnArry.length);

    //a tu adapter le pasas el nuevo array
    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(ContextyMetodos.getAppContext(), flags, arrayFinal);
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spin.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

Para poner un icono por defecto en las categorias creadas, tienes dos opciones, una es agregar mas elementos al array, y otra en el adapter, pongo el ejemplo del adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_items, null);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagenspinner);
    TextView names = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textspinner);
    if(flags.length-1 < i)
    {
       icon.setImageResource(flags[0]); //ponemos la primera imagen del array
    }else{
       icon.setImageResource(flags[i]);
    }
    names.setText(titulo_categorias[i]);
    return view;
}
```

En el ejemplo, a la hora de colocar una imagen, comprueba cuantas imagenes tiene el array, si la posicion de la nota a colocar, es mayor a la cantidad de imagenes, colocara la imagen de la posicion 0, es decir la primera categoria. Me explico mejor:
Categorias -- 5
Imagenes -- 3
Coloca las imagenes a las notas:

categoria 1 -- imagen 1

categoria 2 -- imagen 2

categoria 3 -- imagen 3

categoria 4 -- imagen 1 (al no haber mas imagenes, colocamos la primera)

categoria 5 -- imagen 1 (al no haber mas imagenes, colocamos la primera)

Pudiendo asi jugar con la imagen que queires mostrar.
Si quieres agregar una imagen única para esas categorias creadas, bastaria con en tu `Activity`, agregar un elemento mas al array:

```
int flags[] = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.IMAGENNUEVA};
```

Ya teniendo esa imagen agregada, bastaría con modificar el código anterior:

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    view = inflter.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner_items, null);
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagenspinner);
    TextView names = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textspinner);
    if(flags.length-1 < i)
    {
       icon.setImageResource(flags[3]); // 3 es la posicion de la ultima imagen, es decir, la agregada 
    }else{
       icon.setImageResource(flags[i]);
    }
    names.setText(titulo_categorias[i]);
    return view;
}
```

Otra opcion, seria que al agregar una categoría, se pudiese además agregar una imagen, bastaria con guardar la ruta de esa imagen en una tabla de la db junto a la categoria, y pasar el array al adapter para asignarlas, eso ya es a tu preferencia.

Comment: Hola @Israel ! Gracias por la respuesta! Pero hay un problema, al añadir las nuevas posiciones, estas no tienen un icono por lo tanto no se muestra, he probado a poner yo dos iconos de más en `int flags[]` y añadir dos categorías y entonces si se muestran, habría que hacer que carguen también un icono para que se muestren las nuevas posiciones. Por cierto, es posible que en cada posición que se añada también lo mismo que en las 0,1,2, con ambos `setText`?  En `tv_imagen` recibir por ejemplo "ic_launcher" y en `tv_categoria` el nombre de la posición.

Comment: He pensado en eso de las categorias, podrias crear un icono por defecto para las que se vayan agregando, edito mi respuesta agregando eso

Comment: He utilizado el método de agregar una misma imagen para todos los nuevos, pero recibo esto en el Adapter al abrir el Spinner java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3`` . El error está aquí names.setText(titulo_categorias[i]);

Comment: has eliminado lo que puse en el primer código ?

Comment: Sip, con mi código lo que hago es añadir un nuevo icono en `int flags[]` más tu `getView`

Comment: agregalo tambien, el primero era para agregar los items al spiner y el segundo para solventar lo de la imagen

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61128/discussion-between-israel-and-usernameyo).

Answer (score 0):

Prácticamente ya lo tienes. A tu array `categoria` solamente agrega las nuevas opciones que quieres.

Otra cosa: android maneja la nomenclatura `camelcase` para que la tengas en consideración a la hora de escribir tu código.